# What is the source material, if any, for Sanzoku no Musume Ronja?

Tags: ronia

As the title says, I'm interested to know where the story for Ronja the Robber's Daughter came from, and if it has a source, I want to read it.

Is it based on a manga/light novel? Or is it an anime-original story?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's from a children's fantasy book called [Ronja Rövardotter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ronia_the_Robber%27s_Daughter) (*Ronia the Robber's Daughter*) by Swedish author Astrid Lindgren, first published in 1981.

Comment: The book was also turned into a movie (in Swedish) in 1984. http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0088015/